# Вызов метода контроллера MVC из папки Scripts

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, mvc

Есть следующий контроллер:

```
public class SomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeMethod()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Метод Index возвращает такое представление:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js")

<div id = "place_for_some_content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/SomeScript.js"></script>

<script>someFunction();</script>
```

Функция someFunction() определена в файле ~/Scripts/SomeScript.js:

```
var someFunction = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("SomeMethod", "Some")',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            alert("some alert");
            $('#place_for_some_content').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Проблема в том, что при таком подходе функция someFunction() даже не заходит в метод SomeMethod(), но при этом вываливается в состояние success (алерт отрабатывает), а в поле "place_for_some_content" помещается сообщение "Запрашиваемый ресурс не найден". Судя по всему, скрипт просто не видит контроллер?

Если поместить код функции непосредственно в представление, то все нормально отрабатывает, без ошибок, но захламлять текст представления не очень хочется, тем более когда несколько разных представлений должны использовать одну и ту же функцию, поддерживаемость такого решения оказывается на нуле.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно через ajax-запросы обращаться к методам контроллеров из отдельных js-файлов.

Область видимости для js файлов в вьюшном вебконфиге прописал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался с помощью ответа [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9988634/ajax-call-into-mvc-controller-url-issue/9988672)

В двух словах, изменил вызов функции из срипта в представлении на:

```
<script>
    var SomeUrlVar = {
        URL: '@Url.ActionLink("SomeMethod", "Some")'
    }

    showTable(someUrlVar);
</script>
```

А скрипт SomeScript.js изменил следующим образом:

```
var someFunction = function(SomeUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: SomeUrl.URL,
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            alert("some alert");
            $('#place_for_some_content').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Это решило проблему

Comment: а зачем `SomeUrlVar` объектом делать? можно ж просто строку передать

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я, если честно, не знаю. я сделал тупо как в источнике. вы правы, действительно можно передать просто строку, спасибо